# wp7 - twitter photo upload

Tags: windows-phone-7

We are trying to upload image to Twitter via silverlight code in WP7. We are able to post the message but not the image.

We tried all including download of their library but not getting the hint.

In following link,
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media

there is one point which we are not able to set. 
"Unlike POST statuses/update, this method expects raw multipart data. Your POST request's Content-Type should be set to multipart/form-data with the media[] parameter "

I am not getting it how to put it.

Can anyone please guide me or provide sample for image upload?

Comment: Perhaps if you include your code that you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your photo is called LoadedPhoto, you could create a memory stream from it

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
LoadedPhoto.SaveJpeg(ms, LoadedPhoto.PixelWidth, LoadedPhoto.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
```

Create OAuthCredentials object according to the authentication details you have acquired

```
var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
{
    Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
    SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
    ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
    ConsumerKey = Common.TwitterSettings.ConsumerKey,
    ConsumerSecret = Common.TwitterSettings.ConsumerKeySecret,
    Token = file.AccessToken,
    TokenSecret = file.AccessTokenSecret,
    Version = "1.0"
};
```

Create a RestClient and a RestRequest

```
var restClient = new RestClient
{
    Authority = "https://upload.twitter.com"
};

var restRequest = new RestRequest
{
    Credentials = credentials,
    Path = "/1/statuses/update_with_media.xml",
    Method = Hammock.Web.WebMethod.Post
};
```

Set the stream position to 0

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

Add fields to RestRequest

```
restRequest.AddField("status", message);
restRequest.AddFile("media[]", "ScreenShot.png", ms, "image/jpeg");
```

And then begin request

```
restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, callback);
```

callback is a callback method for the request.

Taken [from my blog post](http://igrali.com/2012/07/14/share-photos-on-twitter-from-windows-phone-app/), see there for more details if you're interested.

Comment: Your example is not working for me: restRequest.AddFile is not accepted MemoryStream

Comment: This has been posted almost half a year ago. There may be some differences with the latest RestClient versions or differences in the new SDK.